# Argument parsing in C++ loop like in Python. Why doesn't it work?

Tags: c++, parsing, arguments

I have tried to create a C++ argument parsing system like it is in Python (`--tag` or `-t` and later the value), but my code will not work. I have doubled and tripled checked it and nothing seems to be wrong with it.
Basically, what it does is it gets the arguments and loops through them all until it finds one that is either `--dict` or `-d` and then the `argument++` is saved in the `dict` variable.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    for (int i=0; i<argc; i++) {
        std::cout<<i<<" - "<<argv[i]<<std::endl;
        if (argv[i] == "--dict" || argv[i] == "-d") {
            std::string dict = argv[i++];
            std::cout<<"Dictionary: "<<dict<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to compare C-style strings, you need to use strcmp().

Comment: `if (argv[i] == "--dict" || argv[i] == "-d")` does not work because it compares two pointers. Use `std::strcmp` instead. I suspect there are many questions at SO about that.

Comment: You cannot compare strings by comparing pointers. You need something like `std::strcmp`.

Comment: If you are not trying to code argument parsing for exercise, you could simply use the [GNU getopt](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html).

Comment: _"my code will not work"_ _"nothing seems to be wrong with it"_ An interesting deduction!

Comment: haha true. Well I did actually realize I'm comparing two pointers and fixed that, but now everytime I try to declare a variable with the value of std::string(stgv[i++]) instead of storing the i++ value it stores the i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argv[i] == "--dict"` is comparing pointers (which will never match). You can compare the pointer contents using `strcmp` or convert one to a string and use `==`

```
// Compare using strcmp
if (strcmp(argv[i], "--dict") == 0 || strcmp(argv[i], "-d") == 0)

// Compare using strings
std::string arg(argv[i]);
if (arg == "--dict" || arg == "-d") {
```